# How can I get traefik to work on my cloud architecture?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, traefik

Okay, so spent a day on my EC2 with Traefik and Docker set up, but doesn't seem to be working as described in the docs. I can get the Whoami example running but that doesn't really illustrate what I'm looking for?

For my example I have three AWS API Gateway endpoints and I need to point them to my EC2 IP address that gets routed by my Traefik frontend set up and then uses some backend? Which I'm still uncertain of what kind of backend to use.

I can't seem to find a good YAML example that clearly illustrates something to suit my purpose and needs.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Any good example Docker YAML examples, configuration set up for my example below? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: what exactly would you need? here's what I can provide.
1. a traefik service as a reverse proxy(with ssl support) 2. for instance, 2 different wordpress installations.
I don't know if you mean that. if so, I can post it in the answer.

Comment: @Cooshal 1. a traefik as a reverse proxy that can manage multiple api endpoints and send back the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had taken [this](https://docs.bytemark.co.uk/article/wordpress-on-docker-with-phpmyadmin-ssl-via-traefik-and-automatic-updates/) article as a guide to provision docker installation with traefik.

EDIT: Before this, create a docker network called proxy.

`$ docker network create proxy`

```
version: '3'

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
  internal:
    external: false

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:latest # The official Traefik docker image
    command: --api --docker --acme.email="your-email" # Enables the web UI and tells Træfik to listen to docker
    restart: always
    labels:
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.your-server.net
      - traefik.port=8080
    networks:
      - proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"     # The HTTP port
      - "8080:8080" # The Web UI (enabled by --api)
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - $PWD/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
      - $PWD/acme.json:/acme.json

  db:
    image: mariadb:10.3
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: r00tPassw0rd
    volumes:
      - vol-db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - internal # since you do not need to expose this via traefik, so just set it to internal network
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=false

  api-1:
    image: your-api-image
    restart: always
    networks:
      - internal
      - proxy
    labels:
      - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:api1.yourdomain.com"
      - "traefik.port=80"
      - "traefik.protocol=http"

  api-2:
    image: your-api-2-image
    restart: always
    networks:
      - internal
      - proxy
    labels:
      - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:api2.yourdomain.com"
      - "traefik.port=80"
      - "traefik.protocol=http"
```

Note: Use this if you want to enable SSL as well. Please note that, this might not work in local server as letsencrypt cannot complete the challenge for SSL setup.
create a blank file acme.json and set its permission to 0600

`touch acme.json`
`chmod 0600 acme.json`

After setting up everything,

`docker-compose config` # this is optional though.

and then,

`docker-compose up`

I have posted my `traefik.toml` [here](https://pastebin.com/NcjPJYgC)

I hope this helps.
Let me know if you face any issues.

Regards,

Kushal.

Comment: Okay, looks really good. Why do I need to have an image for my api-1 or api-2? And can you use existing images to point to your endpoints instead of creating your own. Thanks!

Comment: for api-1 and api-2, it depends. in my case, I used wordpress images. so I can host multiple wordpress installations with out-of-the-box support for SSL as well.

and good thing is, you can also create your services in some other docker-compose file and link it to this traefik network.